# sql select rows that match an evaluated condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that goes like this:

```
SELECT t1.customer_name, t1.total, t2.customer_name, t2.total,
       (t1.total - t2.total) as var_1
FROM topuserslcy t1, topuserslcy t2
WHERE t1.report_date = '2015-12-22' AND
      t2.report_date = '2015-12-23' AND var_1 > 0;
```

I want it to only select rows where the value or var_1 is positive or greater than zero.
Thnaks

Comment: Either (ANSI SQL compliant) do your select in a derived table, or MySQL way, use HAVING clause.

Comment: or just use `t1.total - t2.total` again - but see Gordon's comments below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases in the `from` clause.  I strongly suspect you need proper `join` conditions . . . as a general rule, *never* use commas in the `from` clause.

MySQL has a feature that allows aliases to be used in the `having` clause.  So, your query will run if written as:

```
SELECT t1.customer_name, t1.total, t2.customer_name, t2.total,
       (t1.total - t2.total) as var_1
FROM topuserslcy t1 CROSS JOIN
     topuserslcy t2
WHERE t1.report_date = '2015-12-22' AND
      t2.report_date = '2015-12-23' 
HAVING var_1 > 0;
```

Comment: awesome! perfect answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL compliant answer, use a derived table. Check var_1 at top level:

```
select * from
(
SELECT t1.customer_name, t1.total, t2.customer_name, t2.total,
       (t1.total - t2.total) as var_1
FROM topuserslcy t1, topuserslcy t2
WHERE t1.report_date = '2015-12-22' AND
      t2.report_date = '2015-12-23'
) dt
WHERE var_1 > 0;
```

(But why no JOIN condition?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM (SELECT t1.customer_name, t1.total, t2.customer_name, t2.total,
       (t1.total - t2.total) as var_1
FROM topuserslcy t1, topuserslcy t2
WHERE t1.report_date = '2015-12-22' AND
      t2.report_date = '2015-12-23') as temp WHERE temp.var_1 > 0;
```